# Is there a way in Python to exit the program if the line is blank?

Tags: python, text, line

My file is a .txt file and all comments have no spaces before them.

I have a file with 10,000 lines that looks like this and I am reading every line of the file.

```
## something
## something
## something
12312312
123123
12312312
123123
123123
```

However, my code will fail if there is not a value in every line.

Is there a way in Python to exit the program if the line is blank?

I just need a simple If statement to fix my program.

Something like

```
if line == blank:
    quit
```

Comment: `if not line.strip():break/return` or use a try/except if it is more appropriate

Comment: If you are using a `for` loop, why not say `if not line: continue` instead of exiting the whole program?

Comment: Are you sure you want to exit if you encounter a blank line? Why not just skip blank lines?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely exit the program and the line contains no whitespace(if it does replace `line` with `line.strip()`:

```
import sys

if not line:
    sys.exit()
```

As pointed out by @zondo, you could just use a `continue` statement to skip that line if you do not want the program to fail:

```
if not line.strip():
    continue
```

Comment: In addition, if you also want to exit if the line contains only whitespace, use `if not line.strip(): sys.exit()`.

Comment: Why not just give the `import sys` in your example. "Assuming you have imported sys" doesn't really help!

Answer (score 1):

You could ommit importing [sys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys#module-sys) to run [sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys#sys.exit) and raise [SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) exception instead:

```
if not line:
     raise SystemExit('No line')
```

Comment: That is not the preferred way to exit a program.  `sys.exit()` is the preferred way; `exit()` is an accepted way, but `raise SystemExit` is not.

Comment: @zondo thank you for that note ... just explain why it's bad approach (would delete answer )?

Comment: @zondo sys.exit() just raises SystemExit, why do you think this is a bad way to exit as opposed to using the sys module? Do you have any sources? The problem with this answer is the `line == blank` check, not the way the exit is done.

Comment: @timgeb updated `line == blank` thanks ..

Comment: @timgeb: I withdraw partially my comment.  I have just done a bit of researching and have discovered that you are correct: `sys.exit()` just raises `SystemExit`.  I do still believe that `sys.exit()` is preferable, though, because future versions of Python may change its implementation to more than just raising an exception.  Since that is merely an opinion, I have removed my downvote.

Comment: @zondo fair enough :)